# php symlinks not creating

Tags: php, symlink

i am trying to create a symlink with the target a directory outside my script root and the link inside a folder in my script:

```
if(!file_exists('properties')) {
        symlink('/hermes/bosnaweb03a/b1456/nf.comcan/public_html/properties' , __DIR__.'/properties');
var_dump( file_exists('/hermes/bosnaweb03a/b1456/nf.comcan/public_html/properties'));
var_dump( is_dir('/hermes/bosnaweb03a/b1456/nf.comcan/public_html/properties'));
    }
```

both var_dumps return true. but its not creating the symlink with error No such file or directory. what am i doing wrong here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a permission error. Try the shell command

```
ln -s /hermes/bosnaweb03a/b1456/nf.comcan/public_html/properties , {PHP_SCRIPT_LOCATION}/properties'
```

with the same user running your script. If this can't create the file, then you will need to run as a user who does have permission to create the file, or you can just change the permissions on the location to be more permissive.

Comment: i dont have cli on the server its a shared web hosting. i however changed the permissions on the target folder 'properties' to 777 (was 755). my home directory is the nf.comcan/ folder and i created the target folder inside public_html using ftp.

Comment: Try the updated command. The problem is most likely the location where you are trying to create the symlink not allowing you to write.

Comment: i tried above with exec and got this error in logs: sh: 1: ln: Permission denied

Comment: So that's your problem. What's the full path to where you are trying to create the target symbolic link?

Comment: the link path i want to create is: /hermes/bosnaweb03a/b1456/nf.comcan/public_html/lavro/DirectoryList/properties

Comment: Try setting your file permissions recursively. `chown -R your_user:your_user /hermes/bosnaweb03a/b1456/nf.comcan/public_html/lavro` Here we change the owner of the files to the same user as the one running your script. This us much better than setting `777` and allowing anyone to write to your files.

Comment: /hermes/bosnaweb03a/b1456/nf.comcan/public_html/lavro/DirectoryList/index.php is the file im executing the symlink command from

Comment: What user is running this file? Or is it being run by Apache?

Comment: im not sure how can i find out

Comment: Is the php file being served by a webserver, or are you running it from command-line

Comment: Run `ls -l /hermes/bosnaweb03a/b1456/nf.comcan/public_html/lavro/DirectoryList/` to see who owns the directory. It might be `www-data`

Comment: it returned: drwxr-xr-x 3 nf.comcan www 4096 Jun 6 17:51 resources

Comment: You will need to find the user your webserver is running as (looks to be user `www`), and then make sure that user has write permissions to the directory where you are trying to create your symlink. Then all will work. Good luck!